# Vim: No write since last change, even though I changed the file

Tags: ubuntu, vim, terminal, editor

I'm trying to set up a file on my ubuntu machine, but when I try to change the contents before saving the file I've just created, vim returns the error: No write since last change.

I've created the file with the user, who is trying to change the contents and `sudo vim file.ext` doesn't solve the problem eiter.

Basically, my workflow looks like this:

`touch file.js`

`vim file.js`
In the file:

```
console.log('Hello_world');
```

Afterwards, I'm entering `:q [Enter]` and then the error message appears.

Comment: In order to create a [minimum example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem, please include the commands you are trying to use. From your question, it appears you have a misunderstanding of what the commands you are using actually do

Comment: @jeremysprofile Editing the question to provide more information

Comment: `but when I try to change the contents before saving the file I've just created, vim returns the error` -> `:q` is not saving! `:w` writes a file and `:wq` writes and exits. `:h :w` for more info.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Try this, after editing your file, quit with this command: `wq!`. the ! means force the process, and when you combine it with wq that means force to save and quit.

Answer (score 47):

The error message     **"No write since last change"**    that you encounter basically means  that 
 you have not ***save***
to your file  since the last editing, the ***write*** here have the same meaning as ***save***.

> If you want to save and then quit VIM, type the following 
> ***:wq***  <kbd>Enter</kbd> 
>  or 
> you can also type the following 
> ***:w*** <kbd>Enter</kbd>     <--------  This command is to save the file 
> ***:q*** <kbd>Enter</kbd>     <-------- This command quit VIM

> If you want to quit without saving any changes, type the following 
> ***:q!*** <kbd>Enter</kbd>